# continuous communication with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to keep communicating with a subprocess. I'm trying to brute force my way through. The process starts by requesting a string. I supply one. While I keep getting "No!" as a response I need to try again, until I get another reply.
I created a Popen object:

```
# creating Popen object
sp = Popen(['ba.exe'],stdout = PIPE, stdin = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
#writing to it 
sp.stdin.write(word)
# Read process response
resp = (sp.stdout.read()[0].decode('utf-8'))
# based on resp report success or update the value of word
```

But the read suspends... I don't want to close sp.stdin, as I will need it soon. 
I cant use .communicate() because I need to keep communicating.

Why does the read() suspend? how can I complete my mission?
Thanks

Comment: Does your write include a newline? Programs act differently when stdin is a PIPE instead of a terminal. In unix-y systems you can create a PTY (perhaps using `pexpect` ) but I don't know of a good solution to the problem for Windows.

Comment: I tried with and without newlines. both cases are the same

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling the read method, iterate over lines:

for line in iter(sp.stdout.readline, b''):
  # do something with line

(This should work assuming the subprocess is lined buffered)

Comment: Thanks, 
I tried iter(sp.stdout.readline, b'') and it also suspends.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no newline.

Read byte one by one appending to string and then string matches expected write new word.

```
c = True
line=""

while c:
    c = sp.stdout.read(1)
    line+=c
    if line[-3:] == "No!":
       #do something and clear line buffer
       line = ""
```